# BeautifulSoup - Handing of cases where variable.find( ).string returns empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import sys

import urllib.request
site_response= urllib.request.urlopen("http://site/")
html=site_response.read()
file = open ("cars.html","wb") #open file in binary mode
file.write(html)
file.close()


soup = BeautifulSoup(open("cars.html"))
output = (soup.prettify('latin'))
#print(output) #prints whole file for testing

file_output = open ("cars_out.txt","wb")
file_output.write(output)
file_output.close()

fulllist=soup.find_all("div", class_="row vehicle")
#print(fulllist) #prints each row vehicle class for debug

for item in fulllist:
    item_print=item.find("span", class_="modelYearSort").string
    item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="mmtSort").string
    seller_phone=item.find("span", class_="seller-phone")
    print(seller_phone)
    # item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="seller-phone").string
    item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="priceSort").string
    item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="milesSort").string
    print(item_print)
```

I have the code above, it parses some html code and generates a pipe delineated file .  it works fine except for there are a few entries where one of the elements (seller-phone) is missing from the html code.   Not all entries have a seller phone number.

```
item.find("span", class_="seller-phone").string
```

I get a failure here.  I am not surprised that  line fails when seller-phone is missing.   I get **'AttributeError' NoneType object has not attribute string.**

I am able to do 'item.find' without the '.string' and get back the full block of html.  But I can not figure out how to extract the text for those cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct, [`soup.find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) returns `None` if there's no element found.

You can just put an `if/else` clause to avoid this:

```
for item in fulllist:
    span = item.find("span", class_="modelYearSort")
    if span:
        item_print = span.string
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="mmtSort").string
        seller_phone=item.find("span", class_="seller-phone")
        print(seller_phone)
        # item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="seller-phone").string
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="priceSort").string
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="milesSort").string
        print(item_print)
    else:
        continue #It's empty, go on to the next loop.
```

Or if you like it, use a `try/except` block:

```
for item in fulllist:
    try:
        item_print=item.find("span", class_="modelYearSort").string
    except AttributeError:
        continue #skip to the next loop.
    else:
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="mmtSort").string
        seller_phone=item.find("span", class_="seller-phone")
        print(seller_phone)
        # item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="seller-phone").string
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="priceSort").string
        item_print=item_print + "|" + item.find("span", class_="milesSort").string
        print(item_print)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful... I guess I wasnt that clear on what I wanted to do if the phone number wasnt present.  I actually don't want to skip to the next item, I just want to treat it as a null so my string has || in that location.  However I think I can leverage what you provided above to do that as the error handling part is where I was getting stuck.  I will give it a try in a bit

Comment: Maybe just try `item_print = item.find('span', class_='modelYearSort', text=True)` instead... see if that works - that should only return the nodes that have non-empty strings to start with

Comment: @Jon Mmm.. I thought the problem was because BS cannot find the span?

Comment: @aIKid *sighs* yeah... I think I'll have another mug of coffee :)

Comment: I can see the problem with find, but it is even worse with find_all() in a list comprehension because it crashes. I cannot see a way of trapping that with an except clause or even inside the comprehension. The problem came up when the developer forgot to label the last column in a table. eg [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th)] where the find_all chokes on the blank name.